# Gist not getting color coded

Tags: ruby, github, gist

I uploded some code [gist.github](http://gist.github.com) but couldn't see them color formatted.
I've changed language and tried couple of others which I had code for, but all of them are same.

Eg: [Dummy Ruby code](https://gist.github.com/aniruddhabarapatre/9835384)

How do I make it nicely color formatted?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the way another site formats your content, not directly programming related.

Comment: While gist is a tool used often by programmers, and thereby becomes somewhat on topic for Stack Overflow, this question would better have been answered by reading the Github help. You'd find Github uses Linguist for its syntax highlighting, and, [its help](https://github.com/github/linguist) says "Most languages are detected by their file extension...."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The language is determined by the file extension. If you enter a filename without a file extension (even if you select a language from the drop-down menu), it will default to *Text*.

Add `.rb` to your filename and it should work.